# Fill values in one dataframe depending on values other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have two dataframe as given below

```
df1 = 
    date       balance    month    year    day     month_year
0   2019-10-07   0.0        10     2019      7    October-2019
1   2019-10-08   0.0        10     2019      8    October-2019
2   2019-10-09   0.0        10     2019      9    October-2019
3   2019-10-10   0.0        10     2019     10    October-2019
4   2019-10-11   0.0        10     2019     11    October-2019
```

Dataframe values I have to fill:

```
df2 = 
day October-2019    November-2019   December-2019   January-2020    February-2020   March-2020  April-2020
 1      NaN             NaN              NaN              NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN
 2      NaN             NaN              NaN              NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN
 3      NaN             NaN              NaN              NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN
 ..     ...             ...              ...              ...          ...          ...           ...
 31     NaN             NaN              NaN              NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN
```

I have to fill the NaN in above df2 with 'balance' values in df1 depending on  'month_year' and 'day' values in df1.

I have tried lookup but failed, seeking for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and then replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) or [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df11 = df1.pivot('day','month_year','balance')
df2 = df2.fillna(df11)
```

---

```
df11 = df1.pivot('day','month_year','balance')
df2 = df2.combine_first(df11)
```